# I'm using PyInstaller to turn a .py file into a .exe file, but I'm having difficulty?

Tags: python, cmd, exe, pyinstaller

I've changed it into a .spec file, after which it tells me to run build.py. I do this, but it comes up Build.py: Error: Requires exactly one .spec file, and then doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use the standard PyInstaller script pyinstaller.py, which combines all the other scripts into a single interface.

Just type:

> python   pyinstaller.py  your_script.py

and PyInstaller will create a Build and Dist folder, and put your exe in the Dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. put your script in a new folder.
2. run the 1st script (`configure.py` if memory serves)
3. run the 2nd script (`make.py yourfolder\yourscript.py` again from memory)
4. run the last script(`build.py yourfolder\yourscript.spec`)

you should have an exe now.
good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Following is what I use to make an exe.

using python ../pysinstaller-1.5/Configure.py

python ../pyinstaller-1.5/MakeSpec.py -F --noconsole -n name-of-the-app path-to-your main-.py-file

python ../pyinstaller-1.5/Build.py path-to-name-of-the-app.spec-file-produced

Note: You should need to run Configure only once after a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pyinstaller set in your path variable, as I do, all you have to do is:

pyinstaller -F

And it automatically generates everything else.